# MySQL alter table partitioning syntax

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I tried to do table partitioning in MySQL by altering the table with the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE tt DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, st);
ALTER TABLE tt ADD PARTITION BY LIST(st) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (20,10),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (0,-10)
);
```

but got the following error:

> Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE tt ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p0 VALUES IN' at line 2:

Can someone please let me what's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: That statement is hardly related to your question.

Comment: try this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE orders PARTITION BY LIST(st) (
          PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (20,10),
          PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (0,-10)
);
```

The `ADD` is extraneous - the syntax is essentially identical to the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Make sure you have a good, restorable backup before doing this.

Log:

```
mysql> create table orders (id int, st int, whatever varchar(10), primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE orders DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, st);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE orders PARTITION BY LIST(st) (
    ->           PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (20,10),
    ->           PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (0,-10)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: with or without the ADD, it is still giving me errors.  My MySQL version is:

mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.75, for apple-darwin10.8.0 (i686) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: What do you mean by "errors"? The exact same error, or something else?

Comment: same error.  Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: `5.0.75`? Partitioning, AFAIK, is only available starting from 5.1. What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%partition%';` tell you?

Comment: my version is 5.0.75,  I will try to use 5.1+ to see if it's working.  Thanks.